# Can I use crystal report for print a report from asp.net on company letterhead?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I need to print a report from asp.net on company letterhead, what report
tool should I be looking at.  I am trying to avoid web page print
with url titles on the header and footer.can I use Crystal Report?